# react maps google outsie Grid

Tags: reactjs, google-maps, material-ui, google-maps-react

I use [google-maps-react](https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-maps-react) in my project. On the side on my page I would like to put the map. To separate  content I am using `Grid` and my website looks like this

```
  render() {
   return (    
    <Grid container spacing={8}>
      <Grid item sm={7}>Some content here</Grid>
       <Grid item sm={5}>
         <Grid container spacing={8}>
           <Grid item sm={12}> <MAPCONTAINER /> </Grid>
           <Grid item sm={12}> <OTHER_COMPONENT /> </Grid>
         </Grid>
       </Grid>
     </Grid>
   )}
```

and the `<MAPCONTAINER />`  looks like this

```
const style = {
  width: '100vw',
  weight: '100hx',
}

class MapContainer extends Component { 
  render() {
    return (
      <Map 
        google={this.props.google} 
        zoom={4}
        style = {style}
        >
      </Map>      
    );
  }
}

export default GoogleApiWrapper({
    apiKey: (GOOGLE_KEY)
  })(MapContainer)
```

There are two problems: one is that the map goes out of the Grid , it is very wide, and the weird thing is that when I inspect this Grid element, it shows that it has `height:0`, like there is nothing inside that Grid. The second problem is that `<OTHER_COMPONENT />`  overlap on the map, like it cannot see that there is some other Component above.

I cannot find  way to fit the map into the Grid, how it should be properly.

Thank You from help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Map component renders the map in `<div style="position: absolute;...`
So you need to wrap it in a `<div style="position: relative;`

Easiest way is to do this is by adding position: relative; to the Grid item like so:

```
<Grid item sm={12} style={{position: 'relative', height: '50vh'}}><MapContainer /></Grid>
```

This way you do not need to add style to the Map component

```
<Map 
    google={this.props.google} 
    zoom={4}>
</Map>
```